# Build & Run a dataflow job using custom artifact container

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to Build & Run a dataflow job using custom artifact container but the dataflow job remains stuck for 1 hour and 1 minute and then it crashes.

I am trying to run a simple script to list out contents in a storage bucket. Don't mind the hardcoding in the script.

Here's the main file (dataflow_job_script.py)

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions

class ListGCSObjects(beam.DoFn):
    def __init__(self, bucket):
        self.bucket = bucket

    def process(self, element):
        from google.cloud import storage
        client = storage.Client()
        bucket = client.bucket(self.bucket)

        for blob in bucket.list_blobs():
            yield blob.name

def run_pipeline(bucket, output):
    options = PipelineOptions()

    with beam.Pipeline(options=options) as p:
        (
            p
            | 'Create' >> beam.Create([None])
            | 'List GCS Objects' >> beam.ParDo(ListGCSObjects(bucket))
            | 'Write to File' >> beam.io.WriteToText(output)
        )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bucket_name = 'YOUR_BUCKET_NAME'  # Replace with your bucket name
    output_file = 'YOUR_OUTPUT_FILE'    # Replace with your output file location
    run_pipeline(bucket_name, output_file)
```

Here's the Dockerfile

```
# Use the official Python 3.11 image as the base image
FROM python:3.11-slim

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
COPY . /app

# Install the necessary dependencies
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Verify that the image does not have conflicting dependencies.
RUN pip check

# Copy files from official SDK image, including script/dependencies.
COPY --from=apache/beam_python3.10_sdk:2.51.0 /opt/apache/beam /opt/apache/beam

ENTRYPOINT ["/opt/apache/beam/boot"]

# Command to run your pipeline when the container starts
CMD ["python", "dataflow_job_script.py"]
```

Here's the requirements.txt

```
google-cloud-storage
apache-beam[gcp]
```

And lastly, here are the commands I used to run from my windows command prompt

```
--authorize
gcloud auth login  
gcloud auth configure-docker

-- create docker image
docker build -t list-objects-docker-image-v2 .  

-- Create an Artifact Registry repository by running the following command in the Cloud Shell or your terminal
gcloud artifacts repositories create list-objects-artifact-repo-v4 --repository-format=docker --location=us-central1 --async

--status 
gcloud artifacts operations describe projects/PROJECT-NAME/locations/us-central1/operations/2707c99b-d19d-4af6-83c3-d2cda28472bb


-- Configure Docker to authenticate requests for Artifact Registry using the following command
gcloud auth configure-docker us-central1-docker.pkg.dev

-- Tag your Docker image with the repository URL using the command
docker tag list-objects-docker-image-v2 us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/PROJECT-NAME/list-objects-artifact-repo-v4/list-objects-docker-image-v2

-- Push the Docker image to Artifact Registry by running the command
docker push us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/PROJECT-NAME/list-objects-artifact-repo-v4/list-objects-docker-image-v2

-- Execute the job
python dataflow_job_script.py \
    --region us-central1 \
    --runner DataflowRunner \
    --project PROJECT-NAME \
    --sdk_container_image us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/PROJECT-NAME/list-objects-artifact-repo-v4/list-objects-docker-image-v2
    --sdk_location=container
```

ERROR :

```
raise DataflowRuntimeException(
apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner.DataflowRuntimeException: Dataflow pipeline failed. State: FAILED, Error:
The Dataflow job appears to be stuck because no worker activity has been seen in the last 1h. Please check the worker logs in Stackdriver Logging. You can also get help with Cloud Dataflow at https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/support.
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what are the worker logs saying?

Comment: @CaptainNabla I have posted the error in the end : raise DataflowRuntimeException(
apache_beam.runners.dataflow.dataflow_runner.DataflowRuntimeException: Dataflow pipeline failed. State: FAILED, Error:
The Dataflow job appears to be stuck because no worker activity has been seen in the last 1h. Please check the worker logs in Stackdriver Logging. You can also get help with Cloud Dataflow at https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/support.

Comment: Yes, but from the error message it looks like it is a Job error and not the worker error (like [here](https://cloud.google.com/static/dataflow/images/logs-panel.png?hl=de))

Comment: I do not think you need this `# Command to run your pipeline when the container starts
CMD ["python", "dataflow_job_script.py"]`

Comment: @XQHu How will docker know which file to run? Please correct if I'm misunderstanding something as I am new to docker.

Comment: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-pipeline-dependencies/#pickling-and-managing-the-main-session. When you pass `--save_main_session`, Dataflow pickles the main modules and loads it when running on cloud. Check https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-custom-containers#use_a_custom_base_image_or_multi-stage_builds.